# "A force is acting on a box until t = 10 seconds". Is the force still acting on the box at t = 10 seconds?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, range-inclusion

I have a difficulty to digest any sentence using the word *until*, especially when it is used to express something related to a point of time or space.

In the physics examination, I have a sentence as follows

> A force is acting on a box until t = 10 seconds.

What can we infer from that statement whether or not the force is still acting at t = 10 seconds?

Comment: In the actual physics examination this is irrelevant, because whether the force acts at the exact instant t=10 or not—i.e, whether the interval for which the force acts is the closed interval [0,10] or the half-open interval [0,10)—the answer will be the same for any reasonable physics question.

Comment: OK. Yes, the impulse can be still calculated. Let's ignore the physics. At t = 10 seconds, is the force still acting on the box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As ShreevatsaR says, the question is meaningless in the context of physics.  So here are other examples with *until* where the time boundary can be interpreted:

To my ear, *I was at the office until 5 PM* includes the boundary -- it implies *I was at the office **at** 5 PM.*  *I won't see you until I get home*, on the other hand, seems to me to allow situations in which *I'll see you **as** I get home*, thus excluding the boundary.  Reasonable people may disagree.

Depending on the context, *until now* can include or exclude *now*:

> Expanding the company will change what until now has been a friendly culture.
>   Until now, scientists didn't know why gravity matters.

*Until today* and *until tomorrow* both change their situation at some point *during* the boundary condition/day.

Summary: *until* has no specific effect on the boundary.  The boundary determination, in the rare cases where it has a meaning, is a semantic and contextual issue of the sentence, rather than of *until.*

Answer (score 1):

I think with "until" there is some implication that there is a *change* in the situation at t = 10. This may or not be a change in whether the force is still acting. I think additional info to remove ambiguity will be needed in the next phrase sentence.

Comment: Assume the change in force is the only possibility.

Comment: I agree that without further qualification, the question can't be resolved. At least, as a question about *until*. Perhaps it can as a physics problem. :-)

Comment: @Mike:  Not as a physics problem, since (as ShreevatsaR says in his comment to the main question) the force at a given instant is irrelevant to a physics problem (as opposed to force over even a very short interval, which can be relevant).  It's a language question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ophiuroid that the conditions at the moment of the *until* depend on the context. Here are two examples using the sentence in question.

In the first example, the condition changes prior to the specified moment.

> All of the boxes should be undisturbed
>   throughout the entire process. But—as
>   you can see from the sensor data—this
>   is not the case for most runs. A force
>   is acting on a box until t = 10
>   seconds. At that point, the data show
>   the anomalous force has disappeared.

In the second example, the condition changes after the specified moment.

> Once you disable the alarm you enter
>   the gallery, but then wait before
>   touching any of the boxes. A force is
>   acting on a box until t = 10 seconds.
>   After that, it is safe to grab the
>   box that was moving and exit the gallery.