# "Through" or "to" for expression of range

Tags: expressions, range-inclusion

> 16-bit unsigned short integers that range from 0 **through** 0xFFFF
>
> 16-bit unsigned short integers that range from 0 **to** 0xFFFF

Which expression is better above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In British English, *through* means 'up to' (Monday≤Open<Friday) and *to* means 'up to and including' (Monday≤Open≤Friday).
- In Australian English, it's the other way around.
- In US English, they're interchangeable.  People seem to go the way of the Ausies naturally when they hear *through* in California, at least.

Therefore, the writer has precedence and may assign the intended meaning if he or she feels it is necessary.

Here are some alternatives: from x up to and including y; starting from x ending in/with y; from x, not exceeding y; from x through to y, inclusive.

If you consider *through* as short-form for "*through to the beginning of*" ("through non-inclusive" would make sense), it becomes apparent why British English seldom included y in 2011.  However, if you look at *through* independently, "through to the end of", you could imagine time passing through the second object as a thread passes through a needle.

Comment: In American English, 'through' means 'up to and including' because of pidgining.  People sometimes used incorrect words that were closely synonymous in an attempt to be more clear when there were communication issues.  This is one of those words.

Comment: I'm Australian, and I've studied a variety of mathematical and engineering texts, and "through" has always meant "up to and including" whereas "to" has always meant "up to"

Comment: In British English 50 years ago "Monday through Friday" was meaningless, and unless the context clarified it would have elicited a reply like "what do you mean 'through Friday'?" or "through Friday to when?". Now the expression is widely known, but to me it is still an Americanism.

Comment: Interesting.  Nobody would ask what the other meant in the US, these days.  "Through" just means including.  It's one of those 'absolutely nothing' conversations: "Do you mean to include Friday?"  ....  In the list of weekdays?  Well..., I guess....

Answer (score 17):

In British English, "to" can be both inclusive and exclusive. "Through" isn't usually used in this way.

In American English, "through" is inclusive.

So it depends on your audience. To be safe, use something unambiguous: "through to", or "up to and including", or "to X, inclusive".

Comment: +1 for "up to and including", which leaves no room for ambiguity.

Comment: I can confirm that it IS used this way in American English, at least on the East Coast and on the West Coast, from Long Beach to Sac Town, to the Bay Area and back down.

Answer (score 4):

As a Brit, I would never say Monday through Friday to mean including Friday or not including Friday. I would say Monday to Friday to include Friday. If I meant to exclude Friday I'd say Monday to Thursday. To me through means to some time later. I might therefore say Monday through to Friday meaning throught the week until (and including) Friday but the through seems redundant. As a mathematician I'd use 'to': 1 to 9 (inclusive or exclusive as the case may be), or more technical terms stating whether the set was open at either end.

Comment: So is this you as a Brit or Brits in general? Any idea?

Comment: And are you saying that you would *never, **ever*** say "*(lower-limit) **through** (upper-limit)*"?

Comment: As a non-mathematical Brit I agree with matt.  I would never say "the shop's open Monday *through* Friday".  I'd say "the shop's open Monday(s) to Friday(s)" (i.e. all 5 weekdays).  If I said "Include all numbers *between* 7 *and* 11! I would mean only 8, 9 and 10 (this, though, might be mis-understood!).  If I wanted to include 7 and 11 I'd say "Include all numbers from 7 to 11".