# How to refer to a period of time?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, range-inclusion, till-until

Which one is grammatically correct?

I worked at X company ...

- from Aug 2005 to Sep 2007.
- from A up to B.
- from A until B.
- from A till B.
- between A and B.

Comment: They all work for me though the first is simplest.

Comment: Some of them could mean you worked continuously through that time, others of them could mean you worked only during some portion of that time, maybe off and on during that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All are grammatical. If you’re looking for advice on which to use, the first is the simplest and likely to be suitable in most contexts (although I prefer to write the names of months in full in formal writing).

Answer (score 4):

You should say Aug 2005 *through* Sep 2007:

> **through** 4. —used as a function word to indicate a period of time: as a : during the entire period of [all *through* her life] b : from
>   the beginning to the end of [the tower stood *through* the earthquake]
>   c : to and including [Monday *through* Friday][ [MW]][1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through)

Edit: According to [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_American_and_British_English&oldid=467981128), Aug 2005 *through to* Sep 2007 is "sometimes used" in British English.

Comment: In your reference, it gives two meanings under (b) (c). However, we were told that ***to*** implies the end point not included and ***through*** implies included. e.g., Mon to Fri is excl. Fri; Mon thru' Fri is incl. Fri. There is an ambiguity in usage, though.

Comment: "Aug 2005 through Sep 2007" is American.  The British version would be from Aug 2005 through to Sep 2007.

Comment: @Henry Is that usage idiomatic? I can't seem to find a reference.

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/through#Preposition) gives "From 1945 through 1991" as North American

Comment: @Henry What about the converse, i.e., a reference that lists "through to" as BrE?

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Prepositions_and_adverbs

Comment: Another reference to UK usage, see my answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44686/through-or-to-for-expression-of-range

Answer (score 0):

**From Aug 2005 to Sep 2007** is grammatically correct. I have used it quite a lot when I am writing my CV and I haven't got any problems with that.

Edit: By all means I have to make myself more clear. Imagine a timeline and A and B are just points there. When you are saying I was working **for** company X from A to B these are start and end points of a segment of the timeline. Until, till and between are used when we are talking about activities so referring again to the timeline we are just comparing segments or periods of time. The suggestion below for through indicates period of time too. **They worked through the night.**  --> The period is the night, but this is a period with a name. We have substitute the time from dusk  to dawn with the word night.

Comment: -1. *Through* doesn't have anything to do with time in your example sentence. It's *since* that indicates time there. In fact, your entire second paragraph needs heavy editing. I can't really parse most of it. And your first paragraph only answers 1/5 of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Since these are most commonly used in CVs , you can use **"From A to B"** in most of the cases , or You can also use **"From A till Date"** when you are still serving in the same company when you wrote the CV or you are referring to your present company. But i don't think the last one where you use Between would seem so right.

Comment: "till date" appears to be a primarily Indian usage (I'd never heard it before as a UK/US speaker, but google search shows several hits on Indian headlines);

Comment: Am an Indian :) That could be the reason why i know it and use it. :) You can also use From to Present