# "Sections X to Y" or "Sections X through Y"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

When referring to text that is in a set of consecutive sections, is there a difference in writing

> "Sections X to Y"

compared to

> "Sections X through Y" ?

My intended meaning is to include both Section X and Section Y, and any section in between them.

Comment: With either of these, your intention can be made clear by adding the word "inclusive". _Sections X through Y, inclusive._ I prefer "through" to "to" for objects that are (as here) numbered.

Comment: <joke> Use square brackets for inclusive, parentheses for exclusive. </joke>

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Through" or "to" for expression of range](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44686/through-or-to-for-expression-of-range)

Comment: @KitFox, I don't get the joke.  I mean, of course what you wrote is correct, but what is funny about it?

Comment: @jwpat7: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals).

Comment: @ColinFine, sure, I know all that, but ???

Comment: @jwpat7 Set of people who get the joke = [me, math geeks, you). *wink*

Comment: @KitFox, yes, I sort of agree with that equation.  (Except that the normal topology over a set of people is discrete; every set is both open and closed; hence [me, math geeks, you) == [me, math geeks, you].)  I've understood the math all along, and merely want someone to spell out why stating the obvious is humorous.  :)

Comment: @jwpat7 Oh snap. I walked right into that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is intended for a British audience, then **do not** use *through*. Use *to*, along with *inclusive* if there could be any doubt:

> Sections X to Y [inclusive].

*Through* is so rarely used in this construction in BrE that "never used" may not be too strong. ODO has it as "North American" at [sense 4](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/through?q=through).

Comment: Hmm, the intended audience is "international", as this is a scientific/academic text.

Comment: I've no idea what "international" means in this context. Does it mean anything? If you want something which will not raise hackles anywhere, then use "X to Y inclusive". If you're not concerned about being seen as American and unconcerned, carry on with "through". BrE has seen it often enough to know what you're trying to say; but it doesn't use it itself.

Comment: What I meant with "international" was that the audience is not specifically British (or American, for that matter) English readers, but the international scientific (computer science) community at large. Thus, I would be inclined to use what would be most easily understood by the majority of the readers, however, I guess based on the replies to this question, that most everyone would understand "X to Y", whereas someone might be confused by "X through Y".

Answer (score 2):

Informally, the two are equivalent. Consider these statements:

> The course covers everything about baking from A to Z.
>
> From the greatest to the humblest, all shall be judged.
>
> There are ten questions on this test. Answer questions 1 to 5 first, then proceed with 6 to 10 if there is time.

Clearly all are meant inclusively. If absolute precision is required, as in a scientific or academic paper, use *through*. Otherwise it will be understood either way.