# How do I replace the phrase "As of when..."?

Tags: phrase-requests

I don't think this phrase is incorrect, but it seems awkward and I can't figure out what to replace it with! The sentence I am using is:

> **As of when** the man and woman take him in, his reaction in the face of danger is to curl into a fetal position.

When he was taken in and always before hand, he curled up into a small ball as a "defense".

My point in the sentence is to compare his reaction to danger before and after his major change. Being taken in by the man and woman gives a time reference in the novel in which he begins to change.

What can I replace *'As of when'* with?

Comment: Please provide the complete sentence. It is impossible to tell if these three words are ungrammatical outside of any context. You are asking us to replace "have a dog", but we don't know if the complete sentence is "I have a dog", "she have a dog", or "I have a dog shelters all over the country".

Comment: I have to agree with @RegDwight. Replacing the *'As of when'*, which in some contexts can be replaced with *'since'*, still makes for a sentence that appears to violate the [Maxim of Relevance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#Maxim_of_Relevance). What circumstance are you aiming to describe that the *'curl into a fetal'* position is the result of? How does it relate to being taken in by a man and woman?

Comment: When he was taken in and always before hand, he curled up into a small ball as a "defense". My point in the sentence  is to compare his reaction to danger before and after his major change. Being taken in by the man and woman gives a time reference in the novel in which he begins to change. @Terah

Comment: @Claire - Thanks for clarifying! Could you please add the clarification to the question? That way it will be clear to other users as well right from the start. Thanks! (Also, I can answer your question then, but lift a tip of the veil...Start with 'Ever since' and rephrase your sentence from there on :))

Comment: Please [edit] this to give a much longer context for the sentence. It is impossible to suggest an appropriate alternative without knowing the surrounding tenses etc. Why do you want to replace that phrase? What's wrong with a simple "when"? I'd bet that the reason why it feels awkward is that you've written this sentence in the plain present tense - which is actually a rather marked construction in English. Changing the initial *as of when* won't help with this. The dog's behaviour might be habitual, but the man and woman's taking it in cannot be.

Comment: One possibility is "At the point when".

Comment: 'As of when' is nonsense to me. Reading that sentence over and over, and your explanation, I still can't get what that is supposed to mean. I have some to the shaky conclusion that you didn't find this in the wild, but have written it yourself. For writing advice, well, I still can't figure out what you're trying to say. "At the time when...'? Oh, Ed just said that. just 'When...'? 'As of the __time__ when..."? I don't know. Kind of a mess. What do you mean if you chop it up into much smaller sentences?

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but are you saying that the man **used to** curl up but doesn't now & that during a time he even curled up at being taken in (which to him was a strange & therefore dangerous act). If that’s the case, I think what you’re after with “As of when” is “[Up to/until {**& including**}](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16017)” & you could say “Up to/until [& including] when the man & woman **first** took/take him in, his reaction … was/is …” (there's an issue with your tenses, but depending on the tense & point of view of the narration, either tense could work, imo)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's writing advice

Answer (score 1):

Considering the various comments above, it *is* a bit of a guess as to what **exactly** you want to say, but given your clarification, I think enough context was given to provide you with an answer.

For future reference however, please check the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) of the Stack Exchange site you are visiting to ensure that your question is within scope for the given site. This will ensure that your question is answered sooner, and by people who are good at answering your particular kind of question.

That said, the problem with your sentence is that the different parts of your sentence mean different things to the extent that putting them together doesn't make much sense:

- As of when (Since when, referring to a past event)
- the man and woman take him in (sentence suddenly in present tense)
- his reaction in the face of danger is to curl into a fetal position. (present tense as well)

When you want to express the change in how 'he' reacts to danger from the moment he was taken in by the man and woman (so not before he was taken in), all parts of that sentence have to match up, not just the *'as of when'* part, for example:

> *Ever since the man and woman took him in, his reaction to danger is to curl up into a fetal position.*

Keep in mind that this only says something about how the person responds *after* having been taken in, not how he responded *before* (only that it wasn't by curling up), but for all intents and purposes, this should give you some insight into how the sentence is built up and how you can expand on it yourself.

To parrot myself however, do consider asking questions about correct grammatical tense, etc, on the Stack Exchange that better suits your needs, the [English Language Learner](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site.