# UPTO ONE YEAR BEFORE EXPIRY

Tags: sentence

I'm trying to understand the meaning of this sentence "RE-ISSUE OF PASSPORT ON EXPIRY OR UPTO ONE YEAR BEFORE EXPIRY". I just need help with explanation on latter part of this sentence (upto one yr before expiry) , with an example if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. 1. Please do not type in ALLCAPS on the Internet; it is considered the equivalent of shouting. 2. For us to be able to answer, you must specify what you do not understand, and indicate what research you have attempted on your own. 3. *[How do you interpret 'up to'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16017)* may interest you, as may our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Aru - the sentence seems to mean that you may apply for a new passport not more than one year before your current passport expires.

Comment: Apologies @choster, that was a copy/paste error, not intentional.

Comment: Context seems to be this web page: http://indembassy-amman.org/ReissuePassport.html

Answer (score 2):

This sentence includes the typo "upto" which should be two words ("up to"). The sentence means that you can apply for your new passport within a year before the expiration date. So if your passport expires on April 1, 2017, you need to wait until April 1, 2016 to apply for a new one. You cannot apply on March 1, 2016; that is too early.